# Boost -- Kruskal minimum spanning tree -- guarantee of returning edges in ascending order of weights

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

Consider the algorithm's description provided [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html).

The algorithm sorts the provided edges in ascending order and processes them in this order. The [code example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/example/kruskal-example.cpp) provided on boost website gives an example of calling the algorithm via the call:

```
std::vector< Edge > spanning_tree;
kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g, std::back_inserter(spanning_tree));
```

After running the algorithm, the edges of the MST are accessible via:

```
std::cout << "Print the edges in the MST:" << std::endl;
for (std::vector< Edge >::iterator ei = spanning_tree.begin();ei != spanning_tree.end();++ei){
    std::cout << source(*ei, g) << " <--> " << target(*ei, g)<<" with weight of " << weight[*ei] << std::endl;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the edges of the MST returned back in `spanning_tree` are stored in ascending order of the edge weights?

Comment: It probably should be, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

When we trace the code, we see that we pass a vector of edges called "spanning_tree" to the algorithm, if you check the output iterator (in the boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp header file), then you find that edges are added to it in the ordered that they were processed in, and since in Kruskal's algorithm we should process edges in ascending order then it is guaranteed that the returned vector contains edges sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Could you specify which lines of code in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp do this precisely? I only see a priority queue being populated and then the output iterator `spanning_tree` gets populated with all edges that are not self edge types.

Comment: I agree that the current implementation happens to return edges in sorted order every time, but that's not a guarantee.